# Notebook with windows 7 can't connect to Wireless on certain hours

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

I've been experiencing this problem with Windows 7: when in certain hours of the night (usually between 21 and 00 pm), my notebook loses its connection and simply cannot connect to the wireless network anymore (The little window asking for you to search for solution to the problem open). Some other important points:

- This happens only on Windows 7. I dual boot ubuntu and windows 7 on my notebook and ubuntu works fine.
- This usually happens only in those hours of the day. Rest of the day, it works fine.
- I just moved, and I share my internet with 4 other people. I used to share my internet with 11 other people in the older house, so I don't think this is one of the reasons.
- It's a dell notebook.

I suspect it is something related to interference, because this time of the day is usually the time where there are more people (in my house and in the neighborhood) using the internet. Though I'm not really sure. Thanks.

Comment: What you're describing sounds like interference, maybe a neighbor's strong wifi signal.  The difference in Linux doesn't make sense, unless your wifi hardware is using a Linux driver that is better than the Windows driver.  Save all of your Linux work for that timeframe.

Comment: If you're using a 2.4 GHz signal try changing the channel on the device that emits the WiFi (choose between 1,6,12). So if you're signal sends on channel 6, try putting it on 12 (most default values are 1 or 6, maybe depending on country). You could also use a tool called inSSIDer to see what signals are causing any interference.

Answer (score 0):

With "Acrylic WIFI Free" you can check out at what frequency most routers in your house work. Now just change your router to a less used channel. Won't work while router is on G-Turbo mode, after disabling that you should be able changing channel. Also watch out not to run your router on a channel where other near routers are, better on a channel where a far away router is.